# Processing dynamic MP3 URL

Tags: media-player, media, yahoo, yahoo-widgets

I am using Yahoo Media Player for playing MP3 songs on my website.

I have put some static MP3 links on site.
For e.g.

```
<a href='1.mp3'>Song1</a>
<a href='2.mp3'>Song2</a>
```

And I have put the YMP JavaScript API code also.

Now, I want to load the songs dynamically...

For example if user clicks on a button I want to load a complete new play list to the player.

```
//Something like this
var clickEventHandler = function(){
  YMP.removeAllSongs();
  YMP.addSongs(mp3_links);
  YMP.play();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you, use this:

```
<script>
/** On Yahoo Media API Ready **/
var yesReady = false;
YAHOO.MediaPlayer.onAPIReady.subscribe(function(){
  yesReady = true;
});

function play(){
  //Capture the URL of the song
  var url = document.getElementById('url').value;
  //Put it in Href of Song Link
  document.getElementById('link').href = url;

  //After that Play the Song using YMP
  if(yesReady){
    YAHOO.MediaPlayer.addTracks(document.getElementById('song-div'), 0, true);
    YAHOO.MediaPlayer.play();
  }
}
</script>

<div id='song-div'>
  <a href='#' id='link'>Song Name</a> 
</div>

<input type='text' id='url' />
<input type='button' onClick="javascript:play('url')" value='play'/>
```

Let me know if you need more help.